# sharing object across angularjs controllers using service

Tags: angularjs

Yes, I know this question has been asked but I still have problem following the guides here.

I have two controllers and want to share one simple object via a service as following:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('CtrlOne', function($scope,DataSrvc) {
  $scope.data={
    var1:'controller1 var one',
    var2:'controller1 var two'
  };
  $scope.$on('name',function(){
   DataSrvc.var1=$scope.data.var1;
   DataSrvc.var2=$scope.data.var2; 
  });
})
.controller('CtrlTwo',function($scope,DataSrvc){
  $scope.data=DataSrvc;
});

app.factory('DataSrvc',function(){
  return {
   var1:'',
   var2:''
  }
});
```

I want controller 2 automatically update the object when controller 1 change it. But what have I done wrong here? please advise.

here the http://plnkr.co/edit/LO0qQfyV94A9YEBLsk2R?p=preview code

Comment: I think you are having trouble with `$on('name')`.  Check my plunker which uses `$watch` to update `DataSrvc` values: http://plnkr.co/edit/Sv4QkzvSJlws3963WVec?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to share some data between them and update, you don't even need extra listeners for that and you don't even need a factory. Value storage is sufficient. You can do this:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.value('DataSrvc',{var1:"value 1",var2:"value 2"});

app.controller('CtrlOne', function($scope,DataSrvc) {
$scope.data = DataSrvc; 
})

app.controller('CtrlTwo',function($scope,DataSrvc){
 $scope.data=DataSrvc;
});
```

I have updated the plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/yCqmHMaH6ev9CA2HwQE1?p=preview

Comment: thank you for your answer. But if I want to change DataSrvc from CtrlOne like this: $scope.data={ var1:'some var', var2:'some other var'}, and then assign it to the Srv : DataSrvc=$scope.data; - the view and CtrlTwo will not be updated. pls help.

Comment: it will, it's just that values are constants, so you are not allowed to change the variable itself (or override), only it's value:

http://plnkr.co/edit/CMy8PjVhy4vQYXTtepRv?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing it out. Now I have an idea how accomplish what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an observer pattern. Making your service observable and registering callbacks to notify observers. Using this method, you could subscribe both of your subscribers to your service add a setter for your variables which would then notify all your observers (your controllers).

```
app.controller('CtrlOne', function($scope,DataSrvc) {
  $scope.data={
    var1:'controller1 var one',
    var2:'controller1 var two'
  };
  $scope.$on('name',function(){
   DataSrvc.setVar1=$scope.data.var1;
   DataSrvc.setVar2=$scope.data.var2; 
  }); 
})
.controller('CtrlTwo',function($scope,DataSrvc){
  $scope.var1=DataSrvc.getVar1;
  $scope.var2=DataSrvc.getVar2;
  DataSrvc.subscribe(function() {
    $scope.var1=DataSrvc.getVar1;
    $scope.var2=DataSrvc.getVar2;
  });
});

app.factory('DataSrvc',function(){
    var callbacks = [];
    var var1 = '';
    var var2 = '';  
  return {
   setVar1: setVar1,
   setVar2: setVar2,
   getVar1: getVar1,
   getVar2: getVar2,
   subscribe: subscribe
  }

  ////////////////
  function getVar1() {
    return var1;
  }

  function getVar2() {
    return var2;
  }

  function setVar1(newVar1) {
    var1 = newVar1;
    notify();
  }

  function setVar2(newVar2) {
    var2 = newVar2;
    notify();
  }

  function subscribe(callback) {
    callbacks.push(callback);
  }

  function notify() {
    for(var i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++ ) {
        callbacks[i]();
    }
  }
});
```